# nftables set: Could not add set with flags interval on command line

Tags: nftables

As it is said, this command failed :

```
nft 'add set netdev blacklist blocklist_v4 {type ipv4_addr; flags interval;}'
```

But this one succeded :

```
nft 'add set netdev blacklist blocklist_v4 {type ipv4_addr;}'
```

I tried with flags constant, and it works.
So it seems "interval" is not supported, or am i missing something ??

I'm trying to [achieve something like this](https://xdeb.org/post/2019/09/26/setting-up-a-server-firewall-with-nftables-that-support-wireguard-vpn/).

Answer (score 6):

Don't migrate to nftables until you have kernel 5.6 if you want to have IP intervals !
As [it is said here](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Concatenations) and [SHOULD have been wrote here](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets)

> NOTE: before Linux kernel 5.6 and nftables 0.9.4 the CIDR notation wasn't available, you would need to use a workaround:

No, thanks, fed up with horrible "workarounds". Iptables was able to do that before, and i hate regression. So I will remove CIDR IPs and wrote each IP. Marvelous.

They didn't mention **in the right place** that *flags interval* doesn't work under kernel 5.6. and then you get screwed. Ok, fine. Problem "solved".

Comment: example of workaround: `ip saddr and 255.0.0.0 { 0.0.0.0, 10.0.0.0, 127.0.0.0 } drop` drops all with source address 0.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the version of nftables is too old and does not support intervals.
Please specify the version of nftables, kernel and operating system.